# What is in_addr?

Tags: php

When looking at the return value of [`inet_pton`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) and the parameter of [`inet_ntop`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-ntop.php) in the PHP manual, it refers to `in_addr` in both cases.

A quick search leads me to the [MSDN Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with this answer:

> The in_addr structure represents an IPv4 Internet address.

But this still doesn't explain what the "structure" actually is. When testing return values with `inet_pton` (using a random IP like `219.225.174.153`) I get strange chars returned such as `€·Æô`.

So what exactly is the "structure" of `in_addr` that PHP and MSDN is referring to?

Comment: I believe it depends on what system you're on, but I believe it's linked to C's in_addr: http://www.gta.ufrj.br/ensino/eel878/sockets/sockaddr_inman.html

Comment: those aren't "strange" characters, they're the ascii characters that correspond to `219`, `225`, `174`, and `153`. remember that dotted quads are just a handy human-friendly(er) method of expressing the 32bit unsigned integer that IPv4 addresses really are.

Comment: I was also disappointed with php.net's documentation on the return value of `inet_pton()` not explaining or at least linking to a reference on the data type of `in_addr`. I have seen multiple answers on SO stating `inet_pton()` returns a binary string, but still no links to documentation sources where this is explained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inet_pton()` turns a human-readable IP address into a 4-byte binary string used for network operations, usually involving raw sockets. Those "strange characters" are the ASCII character representations of the numbers 219, 225, 174, and 153 and may or may not have their byte order reversed to reflect the ['endian-ness'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your system.

Every IPv4 address is essentially a 32-bit unsigned integer, and we create an easy-to understand representation of this number by splitting it into 4 separate 8-bit numbers [0 to 255] for what is called "dotted quad" notation.

[image: dotted quad example]

I would suggest looking at and/or using [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) and [`long2ip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) if you're simply looking for a more efficient *storage* of IP address data, and not raw network programming.

Comment: Note that the functions `ip2long()` and `long2ip()` do not work with ipv6 addresses, where as `inet_pton()` and `inet_ntop()` can work with both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses if php was built with ipv6 support enabled.